# Holidays for Christmas

Tags: cryptic-clues

I have applied for leave to my Boss during the Christmas season. You see, we don't have natural holidays during this time.

This Sunday, When I was sipping my coffee in, I received an E-mail from my Boss.
I am going to show you the body of the e-mail in it.

> Dear Sid,
>
> I have heard that you like puzzles very much. I have always been fascinated by those stuffs. So, in reply to your request, I have sent you some cryptic clues to solve so that which would give you my reply to your request. Here are the clues:
>
> play doctor says “Ask me Anything”. (5) (3)
>   A serious tomb (4) (5)
>   Braveness displayed by opener very much (2) (5)
>   Participate with some entertainers (5) (2)
>   A labyrinth for a surprise (5) (5)
>   Walks anxiously to muddled unoccupied area (5)
>   A throne bizarrely made for someone else (7) (3)
>   Redesign Rail for dark place. (4) (1)
>
> The extra numerations are part of it.

I was pleasantly surprised by my Boss's e-mail. I thought that he seems to be in a good mood and would have accepted my request.

**Can you find out, My Boss's message to me?**

<sub>P.S. Deusovi certified cryptic clues</sub>

Comment: Is 'those stuffs' a typo, or was that on purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your boss is saying

> NO LEAVE

Because

> That is an anagram of AVENEOL which you get from taking the letter from the extra numeration, skipping PACES as it hasn't got another numeration.

play doctor says “Ask me Anything”. (5) (3)

> DR**A**MA - DR. and AMA (Thanks @NeilW!)

A serious tomb (4) (5)

> GRA**V**E - @Sconibulus

Braveness displayed by opener very much (2) (5)

> N**E**RVE - opeNER VEry - @MOehm

Participate with some entertainers (5) (2)

> E**N**TER - @MOEhm

A labyrinth for a surprise (5) (5)

> AMAZ**E** - A labyrinth means a maze, and its a surprise

Walk anxiously to muddled unoccupied area (5)

> PACES - Space muddled, and means walk anxiously

A throne bizarrely made for someone else (7) (3)

> AN**O**THER - anagram of 'a throne', means someone else (Thanks @MOehm!)

Redesign Rail for dark place. (4) (1)

> **L**AIR - Rail muddled and means dark place

Comment: Someone else is ANOTHER, an anagram of A THRONE. If PACES is the solution, it has the wrong form; it should either be pace or walks.

Comment: @MOehm ah thanks for that one. Did think my solution made it not a cryptic clue

Comment: First one is DRAMA DR.  + A.M.A.

Comment: That would make a possible answer NO LEAVE - there's no second letter for PACES. I doubt that this made Sid happy. Or did he mean LEAVE, SON?

Comment: @MOehm NO LEAVE is probably right

Answer (score 3):

play doctor says “Ask me Anything”. (5) (3)

> DRAMA: play/DR. AMA (3) maybe A

A serious tomb (4) (5)

> GRAVE: Double def (4) V

Braveness displayed by opener very much (2) (5)

> NERVE: Braveness/opeNER VEry much (Blatantly Stolen from @M Oehm) (2) E

Participate with some entertainers (5) (2)

> ENTER: Participate/ENTERtainers (Blatantly Stolen from @M Oehm) (2) N

A labyrinth for a surprise (5) (5)

> AMAZE: A Maze/Surprise (5) E

Walk anxiously to muddled unoccupied area (5)

> PACES: Walk Anxiously/SPACE anagram ()->space?

A throne bizarrely made for someone else (7) (3)

> ANOTHER: A THRONE anagram/someone else (3) O

Redesign Rail for dark place. (4) (1)

> LAIR: RAIL anagram/dark place (1) L

So your boss

> Wants you to get him an OVEN ALE when you go to the pub together this evening, he couldn't possibly be so cruel as to deny your leave.

Comment: Don't think it can be grave as the first numeration is 4

Comment: Nope, my boss is cruel enough!